NiceLabel Cloud Printing Keeps Saying 404 but not why
I'm tried printing a label using the NiceLabel developer portal to a Zebra ZT411 printer defined in the Control Center. When I fetch the printers, it exists, but when I try to print to it, I get a 404.
GET https://labelcloudapi.onnicelabel.com/Print/v2/Printers

gives me
[
    ...
    {
      "deviceType": "PrintQueue",
      "printerName": null,
      "printQueueName": "ZEBRA ZT411-300dpi ZPL",
      "workstationName": "ACME-3GF58D3.MYCOMPANY.COM",
      "driverName": "ZEBRA ZT411-300dpi ZPL",
      "deviceId": {
        "printerName": "ZEBRA ZT411-300dpi ZPL",
        "workstation": "<workstation-guid-3>"
      }
    }
    ...
]

Yet
POST https://mycompany.onnicelabel.com/Print/v2/Print
{
  "deviceType": "Queue",
  "deviceId": {
    "printerName": "ZEBRA ZT411-300dpi ZPL",
    "workstation": "<workstation-guid-3>"
  },
  "filePath": "/somefolder/hello-world.nlbl",
  "fileRevision": "0.1",
  "labelName": "hello-world.nlbl",
  "quantity": "1"
}


Gives me a 400. I found the file in the API that lists folder contents. I tried changing the deviceType from the default "Queue" to "CloudPrinter" as some examples showed, and it gives a 404.
The file above is a template file with just a Hello World text box and no variables or anything in it.The Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key was added as a Cloud Integration subscription to the acme account.
I hope to get a working example of a simple cloud API print request that prints a template. I will need variable substitution, but want to start simple. At this point, it's not clear that it can't find the template file, or it can't find the printer.

In your POST request this doesn't look right to me: "workstation": "<workstation-guid-3>". Presumably you should be using the GUID provided in response to your GET request.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular I deliberately chose the abstract  to avoid providing a specific GUID for privacy reasons. The GUID in the POST is both a valid GUID and the same one returned by the GET.
